# Can console.log be passed in to test a Ember.js component from my application template?

Tags: ember.js, glimmer.js

I am building a simple button component and I would like to test that my click handler is working by passing in `console.log` (or some other function) into my component. This is in Ember 4.

`app/components/eu-button.hbs` looks like:

```
<button
  type={{ this.type }}
  class={{ this.colors }}
  ...attributes
  {{on "click" (fn @onClick) }}
>
  {{#if this.args.icon }}<FaIcon @icon={{ this.args.icon }} />{{/if}}
  {{ this.args.text }}
  {{ yield }}
</button>
```

and implementation is:

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';

export default class EuButtonComponent extends Component {
  get type() { return "button"; }
  get colors() { return "various classes"; }
}
```

I am calling it from my `app/templates/application.hbs` like this:

```
<EuButton @text="Test" @icon="pencil" @onClick={{ fn console.log "test" }}/>
```

In the hopes that I could see the console print the word "test" on a button click. However, I'm getting:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to resolve a value in a strict mode template, but that value was not in scope: console
```

I have tried passing in `@onClick={{ fn window.console.log "test" }}` and `@onClick={{ fn document.console.log "test" }}` with similar errors.

I think my error is more a misunderstanding of JS that Ember (or Glimmer) so I'd appreciate any help on understanding that function's scope or, alternately, a function I could use in place of `console.log` in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it from the `.hbs` file. But if that's not your goal (which i doubt it is) then you can add a function called an action to your controller `application.js` (or wherever you call the component from; might be a containing component) file and there you'll be able to do whatever you want.

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
// add this decorator here
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class ApplicationController extends Controller {
  // here's your handler
  @action
  onClick(message) {
    console.log(message);
  }
}
```

then you'll be able to call it from the `.hbs`:

```
<EuButton @text="Test" @icon="pencil" @onClick={{ fn this.onClick "test" }}/>
```

Relevant reading: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/component-state-and-actions/#toc_html-modifiers-and-actions or even better https://guides.emberjs.com/release/in-depth-topics/patterns-for-actions/

Comment: Of course, not sure why I didn't see it like that. Thank you.

Comment: EDIT: I thought that would work, but when I try it the `this` is the application route and controller not the component, right?

Comment: Your answer made me re-think my implementation. I was caught up in trying to make the `@onClick` reference a generally available functino. I ended up use making the `@onClick` optional and, if not defined, return `console.log` and that seems to work great.

Comment: @GSP well, yes, the `this` would refer to the controller if you're in a route template or the component if you're in a component. Would you mind marking it as the accepted answer if it was so?

Comment: I don't think it's currently correct (though it was a huge help to me). The `this` in the `<EuButton` can't reference the `@action onClick` *within* the component? If the answer was refactored to put the `@action onClick` function on the application controller then it would be correct? Or, I still might be missing something

Comment: Ok, yes, you're right. Somehow i overlooked it and confused you. I'll update my answer. The handler definition should surely be in the controller (in your case), i.e. at the component caller level